# How to create a deliberate pod skew in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create a pod skew in Kubernetes. For instance, I'd like to run 25% of service's pods on ARM, and the rest on Intel.

Most of the existing tooling is around balancing pods evenly. TopologySpreadConstraints tries to minimize the skew, and anti-affinity will also try to minimize the skew.

The only idea that comes to mind is creating several special labels on my instace-groups which I can spread against. So I could create 4 IGs, 1 ARM, 3 Intel, create a label like 'arm-rollout-25' with values 1-4 and balance across all those.  That feels incredibly hacky. So are there better ways to do this?

Comment: You can use anty-affinty,maybe.

Comment: https://itnext.io/pod-rebalancing-and-allocations-in-kubernetes-df3dbfb1e2f9

Comment: The uneven distribution of the pods can be handled easily by using the \[kubernetes python client\](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python). Using the python script you can get the details of pods in your kubernetes cluster and calculate the number of pods available on each node, use the distribution calculations or create a formula based on which your pods will get deployed to respective nodes using the node labels.<br>

Comment: Hi `Mark Robinson` is your issue resolved..? revert back if you are still facing some issues

Comment: Hi `Mark Robinson` is your issue resolved..? revert back if you are still facing some issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching the way to do this is to create a new node label is not even distributed between nodes and topology spread constraints.

For instance, create the label `intel-arm-25-skew` and break it up into 4 groups. This can be 4 instance groups in AWS.

The result is that you get something like:

IG1- ARM: `intel-arm-25-skew=1`

IG2- Intel: `intel-arm-25-skew=2`

IG3- Intel: `intel-arm-25-skew=3`

IG4- Intel: `intel-arm-25-skew=4`

Then configure spread constraints like this:

```
topologySpreadConstraints:
    - maxSkew: 1
      topologyKey: intel-arm-25-skew
      whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
```

The result will get as close as possible to a 1:3 ARM to Intel ratio for the pods. The downside is that you need enough instancegroups to distribute pods, so it's impractical if you want fine grained control over pod skew.

Answer (score -1):

Kubernetes follows a declarative form of approach in order to achieve your desired functionality you need to define the labels and manually mention how the pods need to be distributed across the nodes, which as you said is a bit too hacky.

In order to reduce the complexity of this uneven distribution scenario we can’t simply rely on kubernetes, we need to use some external tools or scripts using which we can manage kubernetes clusters. There are many such tools and libraries, here we will be using [kubernetes python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).

Even when using these libraries you need to use the labeling concept and resource constraint concept and since you are developing this logic you can modify it any time based on changes in your requirements. The logic behind this implementation is as follows:

1. First compute the total number of pods that are required by your
   application
2. Get the resource details of each node using the kubernetes python
   client library
3. Create a logic stating that 25% of pods need to be deployed on a
   particular node, here you can also take the user input if you want
   to randomize the deployment.
4. Calculate the resource required and the resources available on
   each node, proceed to the next step if the pods can be
   accommodated.
5. Use the kubernetes python client library and deploy the pods as
   per your desired topology.

Comment: This is very impractical solution. Writing your own replication controller/scheduler is an enormous amount of work. The way this is written it gives the impression that this is easy and will encourage someone to build a very unreliable system.

Comment: @MarkRobinson thanks for the solution and providing feedback for my response, based on your feedback I have corrected my response. As per this [official blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/04/17/fine-grained-pod-topology-spread-features-beta) they are fine grading the pod topology spread policies. Meanwhile, achieving the required pod spread relying on external tools and logic will also help even though it consumes some time in creating or configuring them.